# Upgrading Rails 3.2 to 4.2.6, routes generates wrong pathnames for resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm upgrading from Rails 3.2 to 4.2.6 and, for some reason, one model suddenly has it's rails generated resources path names all wrong. Resources for all the other models is working fine.

routes.rb  (commented out all the other routes to isolate the faulty model)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :signups
end
```

rails 3.2 rake routes output (what it should look like)

```
signups     GET     /signups(.:format)          signups#index
            POST    /signups(.:format)          signups#create
new_signup  GET     /signups/new(.:format)      signups#new
edit_signup GET     /signups/:id/edit(.:format) signups#edit
signup      GET     /signups/:id(.:format)      signups#show
            PUT     /signups/:id(.:format)      signups#update
            DELETE  /signups/:id(.:format)      signups#destroy
```

rails 4.2.6 rake routes output

```
signups_index GET    /signups(.:format)          signups#index
              POST   /signups(.:format)          signups#create
  new_signups GET    /signups/new(.:format)      signups#new
 edit_signups GET    /signups/:id/edit(.:format) signups#edit
      signups GET    /signups/:id(.:format)      signups#show
              PATCH  /signups/:id(.:format)      signups#update
              PUT    /signups/:id(.:format)      signups#update
              DELETE /signups/:id(.:format)      signups#destroy
```

Any idea what could've caused this one model to have it's path name changed?

Comment: Is it throwing an error when you try to access those routes

Comment: Have you read the rails source code?

Comment: I think you have something else going on in your routes file, since your rake routes are not outputting normally. You shouldn't have 'signups_index' or 'new_signups'. I'd figure it out since their is nothing unusual about 'signups' as a resource which would require any special inflection.

Comment: I suspect if you look in your routes, you'll find that you have get 'signups/index' which is why you have a route name of "signups_index", instead of "signups". The same likely goes for the other deviations in route names. Paste your whole routes here and we can take a look.

Comment: I mentioned in the post that I removed every other route except signups to isolate it.

Comment: All I'm saying is that your routes are not what you should be getting if all you have in your routes is 'resources :signups'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `inflect.irregular('signup', 'signups')` to `config/initializers/inflections.rb`

Comment: you should add more context, i don't think the poster understands.